# How to configure "appSettings.json" in MAUI as in ASP.NET Core web app/API. How do I use IConfiguration injected in constructor of class?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I need such a configuration in which we use the `appSettings.json` file, so we can put app configuration values into that file. After that, use that configuration in other parts of the app.

We can see such an example in ASP.NET Core MVC web app or Web API.

I am expecting a code which wrapper into method/function, So I can use that method in `MauiProgram.cs` which is related to .Net MAUI.

You can see below example code.

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

    builder
         .UseMauiApp<App>()
         // like as -> .ConfigureAppConfiguration(typeof(MauiProgram), "appsettings.json")
         .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

    builder.Logging.AddDebug();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ConfigurationManager` to configure settings in your .NET MAUI app.

To begin with, add the **appsettings.json** file in your project as an `EmbeddedResource`.

And then, install the two nuget packages listed below:

[Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/)

[Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json)

Add the following to your **MauiProgram.cs**:

```
 builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
 var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 var appSettings = $"{a.GetName().Name}.Resources.appsettings.json";
 using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream(appSettings);
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
 .AddJsonStream(stream)
 .Build();
 builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);
```

Last but not least, on your **MainPage.cs**, you can inject the `IConfiguration` like below:

```
IConfiguration configuration; 
public MainPage(IConfiguration config)
{
      InitializeComponent();
      configuration = config; 
}

private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var settings = configuration.GetRequiredSection("Settings").Get<Settings>();
}
```

For more details about Configuration, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration.